# How to test select2 dynamic tags with codeception

Tags: jquery-select2, codeception

To select an option from a pre populated list works as follows:

```
$selector = "select[name='tags']";
$this->tester->openSelect2($selector);
$this->tester->selectOptionForSelect2($selector, array('text' => $tag));
$this->tester->closeSelect2($selector);
```

Found this gist for that https://gist.github.com/tortuetorche/412fbac4f17db5e78e79.

The issue is that my select2 has dynamic tags as well. (https://select2.org/tagging)

Has anyone figured out how to create dynamic tags using codeception? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I use the `WebDriver Keys` class to tests dynamic select2 fields.
To fill dynamics select2 inputs, you can try this :

```
// Fill your dynamic tag with the option you want to search
$I->fillField($selector, 'Orang');
// Then, wait for the option is loaded
$I->waitForText('Orange', 30);
// Finaly, use WebDriverKeys to select the option
$I->pressKey($selector, \Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverKeys::ENTER);
```

It works to choose multiple options too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need and based on @samuel answer, I added the following method to `tests/_support/AcceptanceTester.php`

```php
/**
 * Fills a Select2 and click on the first matching element
 * @param string $selector the id of the select element
 * @param string $query the query to type in selector
 * @param string $expeccted the expected text to see, by default the query
 */
public function fillSelect2($selector, $query, $expected = '')
{
    // based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/69160282
    if ($expected === '') {
        $expected = $query;
    }
    $selector_name = str_replace('#', '', $selector);
    $container_selector = '#select2-' . $selector_name . '-container';
    $input_selector = 'input[aria-controls=select2-' . $selector_name . '-results]';
    $this->waitForElementVisible($container_selector);
    // Click using JS to avoid error click is intercepted
    $this->click($container_selector);
    // Fill your dynamic tag with the option you want to search
    $this->fillField($input_selector, $query);
    // Then, wait for the option is loaded
    $this->waitForText($expected, 3);
    // Finaly, use WebDriverKeys to select the option
    $this->pressKey($input_selector, \Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverKeys::ENTER);
}
```

Then in a test I can simply right `$I->fillSelect2('#some-selector-id', 'some text');` and the test will type `some text` and click on the first result